# Алгоритм для чат бота с ветвлением

Tags: c#, алгоритм, telegram-bot

Коллеги, добрый день!
Что-то впал в ступор. Не могу придумать алгоритм для чат бота телеграма.
Суть бота, опрос с ветвлением. В зависимости от выбранного варианта ответа выдавать следующий вопрос.
Сообщения от бота могут быть нескольких видов, а именно просто текстовые сообщения, сообщения с вариантами ответов и разные вариации на эту тему.
Для сохранения стадии клиента, создал класс

```
  public class Client
    {
        private int chatId;
        private string phoneNumber;
        private string name;
        private int stage;

        public int ChatId
        { 
          get { return chatId; } 
          set { 
                chatId = value; }
        }

        public int Stage
        {
            get { return stage; }
            set { stage = value; }
        }

        public string PhoneNumber
        {
            get { return phoneNumber; }
            set => phoneNumber = value;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        } 
        public void NextStage(int text)
        {
            Stage = text;
        }
    }
```

Создал интерфейс для сообщений:

```
public interface IMessage
{
    string Message { get; set; }
    int Stage { get; set; }    
}
```

И унаследовал два типа сообщений:

1. Сообщения с вопросом:

   ```
   public class Question : IMessage
        {

            public int Stage { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }

            public List<Answer> Answers = new List<Answer>();

            public Question()
            {
                Stage = -1;
                Message = null;
            }

            public Question(int stage, string message, Answer answer)
            {
                Stage = stage;
                Message = message;
                Answers.Add(answer);
            }

            public Question(int stage, string message)
            {
                Stage = stage;
                Message = message;

            }



        }

        public class Answer
        {
            public int IdQuestions { get; set; }
            public string RightAnswer { get; set; }

            public int NextStage { get; set; }

            public Answer(string rightAsnw, int nextStage)
            {

                RightAnswer = rightAsnw;
                NextStage = nextStage;
            }
            public Answer(int idQues, string rightAsnw, int nextStage)
            {
                IdQuestions = idQues;
                RightAnswer = rightAsnw;
                NextStage = nextStage;
            }

        }
    }
   ```
2. Просто текст:

   ```
   public class TextMessage : IMessage
   {
       public int Stage { get; set; }
       public string Message { get; set; }
       public int NextStage { get; set; }    
   }
   ```

Засунул все это в БД с дополнительным полем TYPE, в зависимости от которого возвращается нужный тип IMessage.

Ну а далее делаю следующее:

```
public async Task<OkResult> Post([FromBody]Update update)
        {
            if (update == null) return Ok();               
            var message = update.Message;
            client = new Client();
            client.ChatId = (int)message.Chat.Id;

            if (!Bot.Contains(client))
            {
                client.Stage = 0;
                Bot.AddClient(client);
            }
            else
            {
                client = Bot.GetClient(client);
            }

            var botClient = await Bot.GetBotClientAsync();
            Bot.AddCommand(client);
            await ExecuteCommand( message, botClient);
            return Ok();
        }
```

А теперь про логику, как это должно работать.
Если подряд идут несколько TextMessage, то они отправляются в чат до тех пор, пока не будет QuestionMessage, после чего выдается текст с вопросом и кнопками.
Ну и по кругу может крутиться несколько раз.
Проблема в том, что если выбираешь следующую на сообщение с выбором, то оно отправляется в чат повторно, чего быть не должно. Перепробовал уже всякие разные вариации метода ExecuteCommand. Последний вариант ниже.

```
private async Task ExecuteCommand( Message message, Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient botClient)

    {        
        var command = Bot.Command;
            
                               if (command is TextMessageCommand)
                    {
                      await command.Execute(message, botClient, client);
                       client.Stage = command.NextStage(message, client);
                    Bot.UpdateClient(client);
                    Bot.AddCommand(client);
                      await  ExecuteCommand( message, botClient);
                    }
                    else if(command is QuestionCommand)
                    {
                        await command.Execute(message, botClient, client);
                        if (command.Contains(message))
                        {
                            client.Stage = command.NextStage(message, client);
                            Bot.UpdateClient(client);
                            Bot.AddCommand(client);
                            if (command is TextMessageCommand)
                            {
                                message.Text = "12412512412"; //тут изменяю сообщение, чтоб не получился бесконечный цикл
                                await ExecuteCommand(message, botClient);
                            }
                        }
                    }        
    }
```

Помимо этих двух типов еще будут сообщения с картинками, карусели, а так же запрос контактных данных.
И не хочется городить тьму IFELSEов. Понимаю, что где то свернул не туда.

upd:
Пример:
Имеется три обычных сообщения и 1 вопрос:
Сообщения:

```
"Я первое сообщение", stage = 0; nextStage=1;
"Я второе сообщение", stage = 2; nextStage=3;
"Я третье сообщение", stage =3; nextStage=0;
```

Вопрос:

```
"К какому сообщению вы хотите отправиться?", stage=1;
Варианты ответов:
"К 1", nextStage=0;
"К 2", nextStage=2;
"к 3", nextStahe=3;
```

Что ожидается на выводе:

```
Я первое сообщение
К какому сообщению вы хотите отправиться? // ожидание выбора. Выбор к примеру 3;
Я третье сообщение
Я первое сообщение
К какому сообщению вы хотите отправиться? // если введен случайны символ, то повторный вопрос
К какому сообщению вы хотите отправиться? //
```

А у меня выходит следующее:

```
Я первое сообщение
К какому сообщению вы хотите отправиться? // ожидание выбора. Выбор к примеру 3;
К какому сообщению вы хотите отправиться? //Задваивается вопрос
Я третье сообщение
Я первое сообщение
К какому сообщению вы хотите отправиться? // если введен случайны символ, то повторный вопрос
К какому сообщению вы хотите отправиться? //
```

upd2:
Переписал код для консоли, работает простым копипастом

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TestApp;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Client client;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            client = new Client();
            client.Stage = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Input Message");
            //  MessageController1 controller = new MessageController1();  //Это два варианта, первый не рабочий,
            MessageController2 controller = new MessageController2();   // второй рабочий, но странно.
            while (true)
            {
                var message = Console.ReadLine();
                
                controller.Start(message);
            }

        }

        public class MessageController1
        {
            public void Start(string message)
            {
                Bot.AddCommand(client);
                ExecuteCommand(message);
            }


            void ExecuteCommand(string message)
            {
                var command = Bot.Command;
                if (command is TextMessageCommand)
                {
                    command.Execute(message, client);
                    client.Stage = command.NextStage(message, client);
                    Bot.AddCommand(client);

                    ExecuteCommand(message);
                }
                else if (command is QuestionCommand)
                {

                    command.Execute(message, client);
                    if (command.Contains(message))
                    {
                        client.Stage = command.NextStage(message, client);

                        Bot.AddCommand(client);
                        if (Bot.Command is TextMessageCommand)
                        {

                            message = "12412512412";
                            ExecuteCommand(message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        public class MessageController2
        {
            public void Start(string message)
            {
                Bot.AddCommand(client);
                ExecuteCommand(message);
                Bot.flag = true;
            }


            void ExecuteCommand(string message)
            {
                var command = Bot.Command;
                if (command is TextMessageCommand)
                {
                    command.Execute(message, client);
                    client.Stage = command.NextStage(message, client);
                    Bot.AddCommand(client);

                    ExecuteCommand(message);
                }
                else if (command is QuestionCommand)
                {
                    if (Bot.flag == false || !command.Contains(message))
                        command.Execute(message, client);
                    if (command.Contains(message))
                    {
                        client.Stage = command.NextStage(message, client);

                        Bot.AddCommand(client);
                        if (Bot.Command is TextMessageCommand)
                        {
                            Bot.flag = true;
                            message = "12412512412";
                            ExecuteCommand(message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        public static class Bot
        {
            private static Dictionary<Type, int> typeDict = new Dictionary<Type, int>
            {
             {typeof(TextMessage),0},
             {typeof(Question),1},
             //{typeof(MyClass),2}
            };
            public static bool flag { get; set; }
            public static Command Command { get; set; }
            public static void AddCommand(Client person)
            {
                IMessage message = GetQuestion(person.Stage);

                switch (typeDict[message.GetType()])
                {
                    case 1: //Question - 1
                        {
                            Command = (new QuestionCommand((Question)message));
                            break;
                        }
                    case 0:
                        {
                            Command = new TextMessageCommand((TextMessage)message);
                            break;
                        }
                    default:
                        break;

                }
            }

            static IMessage GetQuestion(int stage)
            {         
                List<IMessage> IMessages = new List<IMessage> {
                    new TextMessage { Stage=0, Message="Stage 0", NextStage=1},
                    new TextMessage { Stage=1, Message="Stage 1", NextStage=2},
                    new Question {Stage=2,Message="Stage 2 Select stage: \n 0. \n 1. \n 3. \n 4. \n 5.", Answers= { new Answer("0",0), new Answer("1",1), new Answer ("3",3), new Answer("4", 4), new Answer("5", 5) } },
                    new TextMessage {Stage=3, Message="Stage 3", NextStage=4 },
                    new Question {Stage=4,Message="Stage 4 Select stage: \n 0. \n 2. \n 3. \n 5.", Answers= { new Answer("0",0), new Answer("2",2), new Answer ("3",3), new Answer("5", 5) } },
                      new TextMessage {Stage=5, Message="Stage 5", NextStage=0 },
                };

                var quest = from t in IMessages
                            where t.Stage == stage
                            select t;
                return quest.ToList()[0];

            }

        }



        public class Client
        {
            public int Stage { get; set; }

        }


        public abstract class Command
        {

            public abstract void Execute(string message, Client client);

            public abstract bool Contains(string message);

            public abstract int NextStage(string message, Client person);

            public abstract string GetStageMessage(Client person);
        }

        public class QuestionCommand : Command
        {
            public QuestionCommand(Question q)
            {

                Quest = q;
            }
            public Question Quest { get; set; }


            public override string GetStageMessage(Client person)
            {

                return Quest.Message;

            }
            public override int NextStage(string message, Client person)
            {

                var command = from t in Quest.Answers
                              where t.RightAnswer == message
                              select t;

                return command.ToList()[0].NextStage;


            }
            public override bool Contains(string message)
            {
                var command = from t in Quest.Answers
                              where t.RightAnswer == message
                              select t;
                if (command.ToList().Count != 0)
                    return message.Contains(command.ToList()[0].RightAnswer);
                else return false;
            }

            public override void Execute(string message, Client client)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Question message: {0}", Quest.Message);

            }

        }

        public class TextMessageCommand : Command
        {
            public TextMessage TextMessage { get; set; }

            public TextMessageCommand(TextMessage text)
            {
                TextMessage = text;
            }
            public override bool Contains(string message)
            {
                return true;
            }

            public override void Execute(string message, Client person)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Simple TextMessage: {0}", TextMessage.Message);

            }

            public override string GetStageMessage(Client person)
            {
                return TextMessage.Message;
            }

            public override int NextStage(string message, Client person)
            {
                return TextMessage.NextStage;
            }
        }


        public interface IMessage
        {
            string Message { get; set; }
            int Stage { get; set; }
        }

        public class TextMessage : IMessage
        {
            public int Stage { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
            public int NextStage { get; set; }

        }
        public class Question : IMessage
        {

            public int Stage { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }

            public List<Answer> Answers = new List<Answer>();

            public Question()
            {
                Stage = -1;
                Message = null;
            }

            public Question(int stage, string message, Answer answer)
            {
                Stage = stage;
                Message = message;
                Answers.Add(answer);
            }

            public Question(int stage, string message)
            {
                Stage = stage;
                Message = message;

            }
        }

        public class Answer
        {
            public int IdQuestions { get; set; }
            public string RightAnswer { get; set; }

            public int NextStage { get; set; }

            public Answer(string rightAsnw, int nextStage)
            {
                RightAnswer = rightAsnw;
                NextStage = nextStage;
            }
            public Answer(int idQues, string rightAsnw, int nextStage)
            {
                IdQuestions = idQues;
                RightAnswer = rightAsnw;
                NextStage = nextStage;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `А теперь про логику, как это должно работать.` Ваше объяснение логики работы очень неясное. Приведите пример как должен выглядеть диалог бота.

Comment: @Bulson обновил вопрос. Так может быть понятней станет.

Comment: @Ivan не совсем понял для чего 

" message.Text = "12412512412"; //тут изменяю сообщение, чтоб не получился бесконечный цикл "

Почему нужно изменять сообщение?

Comment: @Sterlukin телеграм АПИ работает на пост запросах, которые необходимо обрабатывать. Приходит сообщение от телеграмма с текстом, который введен пользователем. Если не изменить это сообщение, то if (command.Contains(message)) будет всегда true в данной сессии и будет циклическая отправка сообщений.

Comment: @Ivan вы уверены, что это единственно верный вариант работы? Выглядит достаточно странно. Думаю, есть более аккуратные решения.
Нет возможности под отладчиком проверить, почему 2 раза уходят вопросы?

Comment: @Sterlukin да есть конечно возможность, проверял и понимаю почему. Потому что 1 раз он отправляет его чтобы задать вопрос, а второй раз отправляет уже, когда проверяет на верность ответ. Я даже уверен, что существуют элегантные способы это обойти. Но это пока все, до чего я добрался. Даже рисовать пытался, но все равно не придумал ничего лучше.

Answer (score 0):

<s>В общем, сделал костыль, но вроде пока рабочий.
Завел переменную static bool flag в объявлении бота.
На самом деле не понял, почему так, но оно работает. Хотя понимаю, что какой-то странный костыль.</s>
Дело было в проверке на !command.Contains(message).
И изменил код тут:

```
    public async Task<OkResult> Post([FromBody]Update update)
            {
                if (update == null) return Ok();               
                var message = update.Message;
                client = new Client();
                client.ChatId = (int)message.Chat.Id;
    
                if (!Bot.Contains(client))
                {
                    client.Stage = 0;
                    Bot.AddClient(client);
                }
                else
                {
                    client = Bot.GetClient(client);
                }
    
                var botClient = await Bot.GetBotClientAsync();
                Bot.AddCommand(client);
                await ExecuteCommand( message, botClient);
             
                return Ok();
            }
```

И тут:

```
    private async Task ExecuteCommand( Message message, Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient botClient)
        
            {        
                var command = Bot.Command;
                    
                                       if (command is TextMessageCommand)
                            {
                              await command.Execute(message, botClient, client);
                               client.Stage = command.NextStage(message, client);
                            Bot.UpdateClient(client);
                            Bot.AddCommand(client);
                              await  ExecuteCommand( message, botClient);
                            }
                            else if(command is QuestionCommand)
                            {
                                if (!command.Contains(message))
                                await command.Execute(message, botClient, client);
                                if (command.Contains(message))
                                {
                                    client.Stage = command.NextStage(message, client);
                                    Bot.UpdateClient(client);
                                    Bot.AddCommand(client);
                                    if (command is TextMessageCommand)
                                    {
                                        
                                        message.Text = "12412512412"; //тут изменяю сообщение, чтоб не получился бесконечный цикл
                                        await ExecuteCommand(message, botClient);
                                    }
                                }
                            }        
            }
```

Comment: Будет хорошо, если Вы выложите код на гитхаб и дадите на него ссылку. В общей картине будет легче понять в чём дело. Да и проще будет посмотреть в среде разработки. Тогда было бы удобно дать какие-то рекомендации)

Comment: Попробую сегодня вечером сделать минимальный пример для консоли, логика не измениться от этого я думаю.

Comment: @Sterlukin обновил вопрос, добавил консоль.

Comment: Я бы всё-таки предложил Вам выложить это в гитхабе и дать сюда ссылку. И там же в описании проекта описать алгоритм работы программы и с какой проблемой Вы сталкиваетесь. Только разбейте все классы на отдельные файлы. 
На гитхабе намного удобнее смотреть код, там он хорошо форматирован. Кроме того, есть возможность писать комментарии, оформлять пулл-реквесты. Так что закидывайте на гитхаб и скидывайте сюда ссылку (или ссылку мне в  личные сообщения). Буду рад помочь)

Comment: @Sterlukin если еще интересно =) https://github.com/vnstrlkv/Velde_BotTelegram